# Adding html files to a table view in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am very new to iOS programming. I am currently working on an app using storyboard, and I want to be able to display a series of 7 HTML files in a table, which when clicked on each one will then display an HTML file of formatted text.

I have googled to the ends of the earth and back and cannot find anything that answers my question on how to achieve this.

Basically the app has 4 tabs, the first is text, the second is the one where I want to display html files in a table (called Toolbox), the third is a web browser and the last is text.

I'm pretty sure I have my view controllers where they should be, but loading the html files into the table is not happening. I'm not getting any errors when building, I just get a blank table view on the tab when I run the app in simulator.

I'm not sure what other info I need to provide for anyone to help - below is a list of relevant files, and the code from the relevant h/m files. (I can't post images as yet)

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

List of Files:

AppDelegate.h

AppDelegate.m

globals.h

MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard

MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard

ToolboxViewController.h

ToolboxViewController.m

chapter1.html

chapter2.html

chapter3.html

chapter4.html

chapter5.html

chapter6.html

chapter7.html

**AppDelegate.h contains the following:**

```
#import < UIKit/UIKit.h>
NSInteger articleIndex;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder < UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m contains the following:**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ToolboxViewController.h"
@implementation AppDelegate {
NSArray *articleList;
}
@synthesize window = _window;
- (void)dealloc
{
[_window release];
[super dealloc];
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:         (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
articleList = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                @"chapter1",
                @"chapter2",
                @"chapter3",
                @"chapter4",
                @"chapter5",
                @"chapter6",
                @"chapter7",
                nil] retain];

return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
 Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
 */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
 If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
 */
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
 */
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
 */
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Called when the application is about to terminate.
 Save data if appropriate.
 See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
 */
}

@end
```

**globals.h contains the following:**

```
#ifndef TabAT_globals_h
#define TabAT_Viewer_globals_h
NSInteger articleIndex;
#endif
```

**ToolboxViewController.h contains the following:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "globals.h"
@interface ToolboxViewController : UITableViewController 
{   
NSArray *articleList;
NSArray *articleNames;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController; 
@end
```

**ToolboxViewController.m contains the following:**

```
#import "ToolboxViewController.h"
#import "globals.h"
@implementation ToolboxViewController
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize navigationController = _navigationController;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

articleNames = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                @"chapter1",
                @"chapter2",
                @"chapter3",
                @"chapter4",
                @"chapter5",
                @"chapter6",
                @"chapter7",
                nil] retain];
articleList = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                @"What is Anxiety",
                @"Anxiety Symptoms",
                @"Coping Skills",
                @"Visualisation",
                @"Treatment",
                @"Places to go for help",
                @"About",
                nil] retain];


// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this    view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1; 
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [articleList count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ToolboxCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text = [articleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}   
}
*/
/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/
/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.

return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 [detailViewController release];
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `ToolboxViewController.m` is incomplete.  In your code both `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `numberOfRowsInSection:` are returning 0, which is why nothing is appearing in your table.  From what I can tell of your app's description they should return 1 and the length of your articleList array, respectively.  Also you will need to set the contents of the table cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

You could do something like the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{ 
    return 1; 
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [articleList length]; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 
    }

    // here's where you set the content inside your table cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [articleList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks jonkroll, that has certainly helped a lot, I have now managed to get the table displaying the chapter names and I am no longer seeing any warnings, so thank you so much for that. For some reason though whenI click on any of the chapters in the simulator, there is no action, would that be due to insufficient or wrong outlets? (PS have updated code above)

Comment: When you click on a table cell the message `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` gets sent to your view controller.  It's up to you to provide the code in that method to make your app do the appropriate action.  Usually this action is to push another view controller on the navigation stack.  In your code above you can see that XCode has provided you a useful, but commented-out stub in that method.  You should check out [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)